# why my javascript for loop will not work? for (var i=1; i<5; i++;) { document.write ("A statement has run "); }

Tags: javascript

I have tried using alert and document.write. It is from the following [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rDzWA8yPnIY&list=PLr6-GrHUlVf96NLj3PQq-tmEB6woZjwEl&index=11#t=2.832339). It works for him but not for me.

```
for (var i=1; i<5; i++;) {  
    document.write ("A statement has run ");
}
```

Comment: check the for loop syntax again

Answer (score 3):

It does not work, because of the typo

```
for (var i=1; i<5; i++;) {
//                    ^
```

From the documentation for **[`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)**:

> The `for` statement creates a loop that consists of three optional expressions, enclosed in parentheses and separated by semicolons, followed by a statement (usually a block statement) to be executed in the loop.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])
>     statement
> ```

```js
for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    console.log("A statement has run");
}
```

Comment: And please stop using `document.write` as soon as possible. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should remove your last semicolon :

```
for (var i=1; i<5; i++)
```

Next time, you should look at your browser's console, it should have say :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
```